# Woocommerce zip code issue

Tags: woocommerce

In woocommerce on checkout page after filling complete billing and shipping information, goes to cart page or any other and return to the checkout page all information get wanished only zip code remains, how to clear zip code also?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript/jQuery to reset the value of the zipcode.

```
document.getElementById('zipcode').reset();
```

If you are using any click event then you must try the following code also.

```
onClick="window.location.reload()"
```